# It seems xmlnode.Count doesnt exist, but why? Error : "xmlnode.Count = 'xmlnode.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm creating a program in which you enter an IP address and the program outputs a bunch of data about that IP. I'm using IPStack API to get this information. I've been trying it in XML but I'm aware that it can be done with JSON data too.

I've looked at a bunch of tutorials which are using GeoIP ( Which has closed down). I've tried using very similar code but changed to work with IPstack instead of GeoIP.

By using a breakpoint I see that when the line "For i = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1" is read, the loop is jumped straight past, so in this instance I have changed it to +1. I am then given the following error

> xmlnode.Count = 'xmlnode.Count' threw an exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException'

```
Private Sub geo()

    Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList

    Dim IP As String = txtLookup.Text

    Dim APIKey As String = "?access_key=c48babe58dc723c552800c46cbd3c9c6&format=1"
    Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument

    Dim URL As String = "http://api.ipstack.com/" & IP & APIKey & "&output=xml"

    xmldoc.Load(URL)

    xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Response")

    For i = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1 'This is the issue 
        xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()

        Label2.Text = "Country Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim()

        Label3.Text = "Country Name : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim()

        Label4.Text = "Region Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.Trim()

        Label5.Text = "Region Name : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText.Trim()

        Label6.Text = "City : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText.Trim()

        Label7.Text = "Post Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(6).InnerText.Trim()

        Label8.Text = "Latitude : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(7).InnerText.Trim()

        Label9.Text = "Longitude : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(8).InnerText.Trim()

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    geo()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the XML .

Comment: http://api.ipstack.com/92.236.205.233?access_key=c48babe58dc723c552800c46cbd3c9c6&format=1&output=xml

Comment: My copy of the xml from the link above doesn't have "response" (it's "result" instead), but it's still surprising that `Count` would give an issue as the documentation for `XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName` indicates that the returned collection should be empty if there are no matching nodes.  I would expect an empty collection to return 0 for `Count`.

Comment: Okay I must have mistyped. I've replaced 'Response' for 'result'. But it hasn't made much difference to any of the variables when I check them at breakpoints. Any ideas?